# Set a variable name as the value of another variable

Tags: sql-server, variables

Is it possible to declare a variable name based on the value of another variable?

See code below:

```
declare @x int = 1
declare @y nvarchar(255)

while (@x) < (select rd.TimeBucket.value( 'count(/buckets/bucket)', 'nvarchar(255)' ) from DIM_FM_SR_REPORT_DEFINITION rd)
begin
    set @y = '@bucket' + cast(@x as nvarchar(2)) 
    declare @y as 

    set @x = @x + 1;
end
```

Currently variable `@y` is storing the value that I need to use declaring a new variable name.

So at the end, I should end up with variables:

```
bucket1
bucket2
bucket3
bucket4
bucket5
bucket6
bucket7
bucket8
bucket9
bucket10
bucket11
bucket12
```

Comment: Something here seems very off. If you need a dynamic number of variables it is a pretty good sign that you need to reconsider how you are approaching the bigger problem.

Comment: In normal programming this would be an "Array". In sql its a table.

Comment: You're talking to a database server. Those are really good with tables. Consider using one of those. T-SQL does not support dynamic variables in any way, shape or form (except obviously in dynamic SQL, but then only in that one scope you're building).

Comment: You want 12 different variables? Or just this list?

Comment: Perhaps I am approaching the bigger problem in the wrong way. Basically a user will enter information on a webpage, this will be stored as XML. As the user can enter x amount of options, it cannot really be staic with a set number of variables.

Comment: The final thing I want is for 12 variables to be declared. I was trying to get it so that they could be declared after each iteration of the while loop, but I'm not sure this is actually possible